# How to get thrown exceptions of a java function?

Tags: java, function

I am reading the Hadoop source code, and I need to know what the exceptions are thrown by the specific function.

Is there a command or tool can find function definition in java project? I have to find a lot of function definition and analyze them, therefore the textual finding results are needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Any IDE can do that, e.g. IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans, etc...

Comment: You can get the declared exceptions [by reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getExceptionTypes--)

Comment: @Andy Turner: Thanks you, it helps me, I get exception type by `method.getExceptionTypes()`